# Proof: convergence about power series

Tags: convergence-divergence

$\sum  a_n  x^n$     power series
If the coefficients  $a_n$ equal the answers of a family of counting problems indexed by n
we call the power series a generating function for the counting problem.
$1 + x + 2x^2 + 6x^3 + 24x^4 +$  equals the generating function for the problem of
                               counting ways to order an n element set

How to prove that this never converges for any x except 0?

Comment: Note that the general term $a_n$ diverges

Answer (score 0):

$$1+x+2x^2+6x^3+24x^4+120x^5+\cdots=\\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n!\times x^{n}\\$$suppose $|x|<1$ now take $$x=\frac{1}{k} , \space |k|>1$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\\\lim_{n\to \infty}n!x^n=\\\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!}{k^n} \to \infty$$

Comment: Your welcome . Hope it useful...